# Formatting cells in Excel with Python

Tags: python, excel, formatting

How do I format cells in Excel with python?

In particular I need to change the font of several subsequent rows 
to be regular instead of bold.

Comment: you must have already looked 
 at 
http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2005-June/326410.html

Answer (score 3):

Using [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt):

```
from xlwt import *

font0 = Font()
font0.bold = False

style0 = XFStyle()
style0.font = font0

wb = Workbook()
ws0 = wb.add_sheet('0')

ws0.write(0, 0, 'myNormalText', style0)

font1 = Font()
font1.bold = True

style1 = XFStyle()
style1.font = font1

ws0.write(0, 1, 'myBoldText', style1)

wb.save('format.xls')
```

Comment: Note: you most likely won't want to use "from module_name import *" in practice, this is used here for illustrative purposes only.

Answer (score 3):

For using Python for Excel operations in general, I highly recommend checking out [this site](http://www.python-excel.org/).  There are three python modules that allow you to do pretty much anything you need: *xlrd* (reading), *xlwt* (writing), and *xlutils* (copy/modify/filter).  On the site I mentioned, there is quite a bit of associated information including documentation and examples.  In particular, you may be interested in [this example](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlutils/trunk/xlutils/docs/styles.txt).  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For generic examples of Excel scripting from Python, [this snippet](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2036) is very handy. It doesn't specifically do the "change font to regular", but that's just `range.Font.Bold = False` in a function otherwise very similar to the `set_border` one in that snippet.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.dev-explorer.com/articles/excel-spreadsheets-and-python) is a brief introduction to using `xlwt` and the complementary `xlrd` (for reading `.xls` files). However, the Reddit [thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/8nwc9/reading_and_writing_to_excel_spreadsheets_in/c09wou0) where I discovered that article has a huge number of useful bits of advice, including some cautionary notes and how to use the `win32com` module to write Excel files better (see [this comment](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/8nwc9/reading_and_writing_to_excel_spreadsheets_in/c09w5a0), for example) - frankly, I think the code is easier to read/maintain. You can probably learn a lot more over at the pretty active [python-excel](http://groups.google.com/group/python-excel/?pli=1) group.